# Do Australian and Canadian wizards say "Muggle" or "No-Maj"?

Tags: harry-potter, terminology

In the USA, non-magic people are called "No-Maj(e)s" rather than Muggles. What is the term used in Canada and Australia? Since they're Commonwealth Realms, it's likely they also say Muggle. OTOH, Canada or most of Canada attends Ilvermorny and Australia is believed to have an own wizarding school, so they might say No-Maj or use both terms interchangeably.

Perhaps western Canada (west of Quebec and Nunavut) rather uses No-Maj while Nunavut and Atlantic Canada say Muggle. Or only Atlantic Canada or perhaps only Newfoundland and Labrador say Muggle. I believe Newfoundlanders attend Hogwarts because they were British until 1949.

Comment: And then there is Quebec proper and St Pierre and Miquelon which may send students to Beauxbatons?

Comment: @JonCuster Yes I believe so. St Pierre et Miquelon anyway as it belongs to France. Distance doesn't matter in the magic world due to the floo network.